# Microsoft Access - copy object properties to another object of the same type

Tags: ms-access, button, properties

I know you can select multiple objects and you will be able to change all of the properties that they have in common. In most cases, this would be ideal; however, I have multiple forms that I want to copy the properties of buttons to.

Is there a way I can copy the properties of one button to another button in a different form?

I could copy and paste the button, however it would mean copying the code from each button and pasting the code to the new button. Which really would be a pain as there are a lot of buttons with a lot of code.

Any ideas, or do I have to do this the hard way?

Comment: When you paste a button to another form, the code not copied automatically. Then you can copy properties to other buttons on the form

Comment: @SergeyS. I've just figured it out, you can copy the object and 'paste formatting' to the new object. It will copy the objects properties straight over

Answer (score 3):

Literally just figured it out:

- Copy the object that you wish to copy the properties from
- Right click the object that you want to copy the properties to
- Select 'Paste Formatting'

Not sure if this works when the objects are different, but it does work if the objects are the same type.